# Unix grep regex how to grep for

Tags: regex

I have a text file

```
$ cat test.log
SYB-01001
SYB-18913
SYB-02445
SYB-21356
```

I want to grep for 01001 and 18913 only whats the way to do this

I want the output to be

```
SYB-01001
SYB-18913
SYB-02445
```

I tried this but not sure whats wrong with it

```
grep 'SYB-(18913)|0*)' test.log
```

Comment: Think you might need to re-explain - the output you expect doesn't really match up with what you say you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-E` flag for "extended regular expressions" with grep.

e.g.

```
grep -E 'SYB-(0|18913)' test.log
```

Other things to be aware of:

- parentheses must match (for every opening bracket you want a closing bracket)
- `0*` means zero or more `0` characters - in truth this will match everything

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
grep 'SYB-\(18913\|0*\)' test.log
```

But you maybe don't want the `0*` part to act like this. Maybe `0+` is better.

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
awk '/SYB-(0|18913)/' file
```

Answer (score -1):

Your brackets are out.  Try

```
grep 'SYB-[18913|0*]' test.log
```

Comment: Checked it on Linux Mint, gets the same output as the question was expecting.

Comment: `echo "SYB-11111" | grep 'SYB-[18913|0*]'`